# Linux c fork - process dont stop

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

I'm trying to create simple program with using pipes. Unfortunately program donesn't end correctly as if some descriptor was not closed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    if(fork()==0){
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1],1);
        close(fd[1]);
        execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
    }
    else{
       if(fork() == 0){
           close(fd[1]);
           dup2(fd[0],0);
           close(fd[0]);
           execlp("tr", "tr", "a-z", "A-Z", NULL);
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The general pattern is `dup2(fd[0], 0); close(fd[0]); close(fd[1]);`  That is, dup one side of the pipe, then close both sides.

Comment: Think of it this way: you want `ls` to run with exactly 3 file descriptors open.  Since the parent has called pipe, the parent has 5 open when it calls fork.  So the child starts with 5 open fd.  When you call dup2, one is closed and one is opened, so you still have 5 (the 2nd argument is closed and then re-opened).  You need to close 2 of them to get down to 3.

Comment: How can I close 2 of them? Where in my code should I use close function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as all the functions succeed (you should absolutely do error-checking in the production version, though), your program should work fine.

If you want to wait for the two children, however:

```
 wait(0); wait(0); //also skimping on the error checking
 //stuck
 return 0;
```

it will get stuck because `tr` will try to read its whole `stdin` (the pipe) and the pipe can't end as long as the parent still holds a reference to the write end.

With

```
 close(fd[1]);
 wait(0); wait(0); //also skimping on the error checking
 //stuck
 return 0;
```

it should again run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

The program gives the impression it "doesn't end" because both operations are done in a forked process, and the main process dies ahead of the 2 children, thus gives back the hand to the *shell* before the results are printed.

Add this line before the `return 0`

```
     wait(NULL);
```

to have the main process wait for all children before dying, to fix this.

Note that you could also not fork *again* the main process (that does the `tr`) and you'd get the same result.

```
else{
      close(fd[1]);
      dup2(fd[0],0);
      close(fd[0]);
      execlp("tr", "tr", "a-z", "A-Z", NULL);
}
```

Comment: I know it, but it's only simplification of bigger project, so i write there only simple and general core of the problem. Thank you for your answer.